# Подключить класс с другого сервера

Tags: php, ооп

Как можно  кодключить класс с другого сервера. Пробовал

```
require_once 'http://site.ru/class/ip.php';
```

но в результате получаю Fatal error

Comment: если сервер правильно настроен, он не отдаст текст php скрипта, а только результат его выполнеия, поэтому - никак

Comment: Файл класса переименовать в txt, затем достать его через file_get_contents и вылополнить код в eval